# Storing data from jfilechooser

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, stringbuilder, jfilechooser

So I'm writing a car loan amortization GUI program. The end goal is to get either user input data or input from a file and display the payment schedule. I have the user input schedule displaying to the console window for now but my main question is how do I store the data from the text file into variables in order to plug them into the equation?

I am using `scanner` and `stringbuilder` and am able to display the contents of the file in the console window, but can't figure out how to store the values into variables. Also if anyone has any tips as to how to display the schedule from the console window onto a second GUI, that would be nice as well.

```
    File workingDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

    JFileChooser openfile = new JFileChooser();
    openfile.setDialogTitle("Choose a file");
    openfile.setCurrentDirectory(workingDir);

    int status = openfile.showOpenDialog(null);

    try {
        if(status != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            return null; // error 
        }
        else {
            File file = openfile.getSelectedFile();
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();

            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                String data = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println(data);
            }

        }   

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {

    }
return null;
}`
```

Comment: Well, this would entirely depend upon how you have the data stored within the file (provide an example with fictitious data) and what variable names (and Data Type) you want for each specific piece of file data. You haven't specified either and therefore there is no real conclusive way to tell you.

Comment: The text file contains 3 values, (6500, 4.5, 6) and i want their variables to be along of the lines of totalAmount, interestAmount, and durationAmount respectively. Also would most likely use doubles for all three as that’s what  i used for the users input.

Answer (score 0):

Your obviously not showing the actual method declaration for your sample code and by the look of it your data file only contains a single line so I'm just going to wing it here.

Everything within a text file is considered as String content. To convert the data within a text file you would need to use parsers. Your comma delimited file data line contains 3 specific values which would definitely benefit (for now) being of **double** data type. In order to segment this data line and place the value contents into double type variables you would need to use the **String.split()** method:

In my opinion I think it's just better to read each file line in its entirety by using **hasNextLine()** in conjunction with **scan.NextLine()** rather than **hasNext()**:

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String data = scan.nextLine();
    // Skip blank lines or possible comment lines
    // (lines that start with a semi-colon). 
    if (data.trim().equals("") || data.trim().startsWith(";")) {
        continue;
    } 
    // Create an Array of string values.
    String[] stringValues = data.split(", ");
}
```

This now creates a String Array with each element of that array containing the individual values that were contained on the file data line:

- stringValues[**0**] will hold the string: **6500**
- stringValues[**1**] will hold the string: **4.5**
- stringValues[**2**] will hold the string: **6**

Remember, Array indexing starts from 0 not 1. Now all that is needed is to convert and place these elements into individual **double** data type variables and we can do that like this.

```
double totalAmount = Double.parseDouble(stringValues[0]);
double interestAmount = Double.parseDouble(stringValues[1]);
double durationAmount = Double.parseDouble(stringValues[2]);
```

Your **while** loop could now possibly look like this:

```
double totalAmount = 0.0;
double interestAmount = 0.0;
double durationAmount = 0.0;

while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String data = scan.nextLine();
    // Skip blank lines or possible comment lines
    // (lines that start with a semi-colon). 
    if (data.trim().equals("") || data.trim().startsWith(";")) {
        continue;
    } 
    // Create an Array of string values.
    String[] stringValues = data.split(", ");

    // Convert String Array elements to their 
    // respective double type variables.
    totalAmount = Double.parseDouble(stringValues[0]);
    interestAmount = Double.parseDouble(stringValues[1]);
    durationAmount = Double.parseDouble(stringValues[2]);
}
// rest of code here.....
```

Now it's a matter of you using those double type variables as you see fit to carry out your calculations.

As for displaying a schedule within a GUI I would recommend the use of a JTable. Create your GUI and add a JTable. For now just have all cells accept String rather than specific data types. To add rows of data to your JTable you can use a method like this:

```
private void addRowToJTable(JTable table, Object[] rowData) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.addRow(rowData);
}
```

The Object Array you pass to this method would contain elements that represent each column of the table. A simple use case would be:

```
// Table Columns:  Payment #, Pymt Date, Payment, Interest, Principle, Balance
Object[] rowData = {"1", "Jun 12, 2018", "$112.39", "$40.63", "$71.76", "$6,428.24"};
addRowToJTable(jTable1, rowData);
```

Of course you would have this code in a loop of some sort as you build your schedule. If you would like a runnable example application I quickly whipped up to demonstrate this stuff then send me an e-mail. Your example data line could produce a schedule that could look something like this:

[image]